# How to get an XML attribute's value?

Tags: xml, delphi

Given the XML snippet below, how can I get the value of the XML attribute `TEXT`?

```
<POPULARITY URL="example.com"  SOURCE="panel" TEXT="27503270" />
```

Negative...

MY CODES...:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i:integer;
begin
   if kontrol=0 then
   begin
      XMLDocument1.Active:=false;
      XMLDocument1.FileName:='http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=aliatabak.com';
      XMLDocument1.Active:=true;
   end;
   i:=1;
   baslangic:=XMLDocument1.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.FindNode('SD');
   repeat
      isim:=baslangic.ChildNodes.Nodes['??????'].Text;

      edit1.Text:=isim;

      i:=i+1;
      baslangic:=baslangic.NextSibling;
   Until baslangic=nil;

end;
```

Answer (score 12):

Use the `IXMLNode.Attributes` property:

```
isim := VarToStr(baslangic.Attributes['TEXT']);
```

Or the `IXMLNode.AttributeNodes` property:

```
Isim := baslangic.AttributeNodes.Nodes['TEXT'].Text;
```

Or:

```
Attr := baslangic.AttributeNodes.FindNode('TEXT');
If Attr <> nil then
    isim := Attr.Text;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use XPath to retrieve the value

Try this sample app

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  MSXML,
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  Variants;

procedure GetInfoXML;
const
 URI='http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=aliatabak.com';
 OK       =200;
 COMPLETED=4;
var
  XMLHTTPRequest  : IXMLHTTPRequest;
  XMLDOMDocument  : IXMLDOMDocument;
  XMLDOMNode      : IXMLDOMNode;
begin
    XMLHTTPRequest := CreateOleObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP') As IXMLHTTPRequest;
  try
    XMLHTTPRequest.open('GET', URI, False, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
    XMLHTTPRequest.send('');
    if (XMLHTTPRequest.readyState = COMPLETED) and (XMLHTTPRequest.status = OK) then
    begin
      XMLDOMDocument := XMLHTTPRequest.responseXML  As IXMLDOMDocument2;
      //get the node 
      XMLDOMNode := XMLDOMDocument.selectSingleNode('//ALEXA/SD/POPULARITY');
      //get the "TEXT" attribute
      Writeln(Format('%s',[String(XMLDOMNode.attributes.getNamedItem('TEXT').Text)]));
    end;
  finally
    XMLHTTPRequest := nil;
  end;
end;

begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      GetInfoXML;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the XML into Delphi classes using XMLDataBinding (File/New/Othe/XML/XMLDataBinding), choosing your "Alexa.XML" file.
Delphi will generate a file (Alexa.pas, for example) with the interfaces and classes to deal with your XML data.

With the XML mapped to Delphi classes, you can easily walk through the XML data.

Example:

```
function TYourClass.GetAlexaText(const FileName: string): string;
var
  XMLDoc1: TXMLDocument;
  Alexa: IXMLALEXAType;
begin
  XMLDoc1 := TXMLDocument.Create(Self);
  XMLDoc1.FileName := FileName;
  XMLDoc1.Active := True;
  Alexa := GetAlexa(XMLDoc1);
  Result := IntToStr(Alexa.SD[1].POPULARITY.TEXT);
end;
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

```
isim:=baslangic.ChildNodes['POPULARITY'].AttributeNodes['TEXT'].text;
```

i have found.. Thanks.